# How to send data to one script for as long as correct data from another script is being received using zmq

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

Hello guys and girls I could really use your help or guidance on this problem.

Given I have 3 python scripts

**script1.py**

**script2.py**

**script3.py**

What I need is for script1.py to send let's say a string 'True' to script2.py.

Then script2.py must send a string to script3.py.

In the same time script2.py must check wether script1.py sends him a string 'False'.

If that happens, script2.py must stop sending any data to script3.py

I am using pyzmq, as I think it is going to fit my needs. I don't want to use Flask or socketsio.

I have looked at multiprocessing and multithreading, but I am not sure if that is the direction I should move to. I have tried using while loops to check constantly the values send from one script to the other, but this does not work very well.

Is there a way to do this using only pyzmq or should I use something like multiprocessing or multithreading indeed?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: **Trying to give a better explanation.**

This is the script2.py. It gets the data through port 5555 from script1.py and publishes other data through port 5556 to script3.py by running the function get(). At this point I thought data1 to be the input from script1.py. I want to check all the time if script1.py sends me a signal to stop publishing the data to script3.py.

Is there a way to do this using pyzmq without using parallel computing?

```
#script2.py
from time import sleep
import random
import zmq

def get():
    estimated = ()
    on = ()

    i = 0   
    while i<10:
        now = random.uniform(10, 15)
        estimated += (now,)
        on += (0.85 * now,)
        sleep(1)
        i += 1

    data_package = {'Estimated ': estimated, 'Actual': on}
    return data_package

context = zmq.Context()

socket_1 = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket_1.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'status')
socket_1.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
print('Connected to port 5555')
topic1 = socket1.recv_string()
data1 = socket1.recv_string() # may be a pyobj as well

socket2 = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket2.bind("tcp://*:5556")
print('Connected to port 5556')

while True:
    socket_2.send_string('topic2', zmq.SNDMORE)
    socket_2.send_pyobj(get())
    print("dictionary sent")
```

Right now it just runs the while loop endlessly. Putting the received string as a condition does not really do anything.

Comment: This is a bit broad. There are myriad ways to do this, so you're going to receive widely variant and speculative answers. Please narrow down the scope of the question and, preferably, include some code as an [mcve]. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended using multiprocessing. It does what I want, closing the question. Probably was broad indeed.